# How to apply class to a dynamic inserted html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery Mask Plugin v1.5.3 - jquery-1.9.1.js

and I have this button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add_employee" value="add employee" />
```

to add some html code with Jquery that follow:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#add_employee").click(function() {
    var html = "<tr><td>";
    html += "<input name=\'w_hour[]\' class=\'number\' type=\'text\'>";
    html += "</td></tr>";
    $("#detail").html(html);
   });
 });
```

I have this line to setup html input text with Jquery mask:

```
$('.number').mask('000,000.00', {reverse: true});
```

For items originally created with the page works fine when the DOM is initialized.

My question is, How to apply the Jquery mask to a new inserted html element to the DOM, (in this case Input-text) to get this feature. The code in particular is:

```
html += "<td><input name=\'w_hour[]\' class=\'number\' type=\'text\'></td>";
```

Because, when I try to write numbers does not get the Jquery mask, I guess that is because it is a new element inserted. I not sure I am new with Jquery, so I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: do the mask after creating the elements.

Comment: you can call that mask in side the **#add_employee** click function

Comment: I tried to put the Jquery Mask after inserting the html code but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a new DOM element so the events do not get attached to this element dynamically you have tell the DOM that the new element will use the mask prototype so replace your code with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#add_employee").click(function() {
    var html = "<tr><td>";
    html += "<input name=\'w_hour[]\' class=\'number\' type=\'text\'>";
    html += "</td></tr>";
    $("#detail").html(html);
    $('.number').mask('000,000.00', {reverse: true});
   });
 });
```

this will work fine because now after inserting the new element we are leting the js engine to know that the newly created elements will have mask protype.

Comment: Thanks Adesh, I think I was making a mistake by putting the code of Jquery Mask before for the new elements. Great I fix the problem thanks again.